# How come, after editing my GPG key multiple changes, it is still working for file decryption?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, photos

In [this GPG key of mine](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x4311D0FB042CB88F&fingerprint=on&op=vindex), I have / at the time of reading likely have had an unfortunate photo:

[image: Old GPG photo]

I am still undecided what picture (if any) to put in there, likely this one:

[image: New GPG photo]

No matter which one I end up choosing, I would like to ask How come after editing my GPG key (with even name change), it is still working for encryption/decryption of my files.

I originally thought I would ruin it by editing said GPG key.

And can I really edit everything including email address with it still to be working? In what scenario would it hinder something in case not working for all cases?

If so, how is that possible?

Many thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual encryption key doesn't change, only the metadata attached to it does. The name and email address never had anything to do with encryption – they are only used by mail apps to *find* the right key in the sender's keyring.

See `gpg --export yourkey | sq inspect`, `| sq packet dump`, or `| pgpdump`. You'll see that what you call "the key" is not the key but a bundle of various packets (with more than just one actual key inside).

```
$ gpg --export 0x4311D0FB042CB88F | sq packet dump

Public-Key Packet, old CTB, 525 bytes              <-- The RSA keypair used
    Version: 4                                         for signing.
    Pk algo: RSA
    Pk size: 4096 bits
    Fingerprint: 055667909AA5B877B2A47BC34311D0FB042CB88F
    KeyID: 4311D0FB042CB88F
  
User ID Packet, old CTB, 55 bytes                  <-- A name & email (there can
                                                       can be multiple of those).
    Value: Vlastimil Burian (ProtonMail) <info@vlastimilburian.cz>
  
Signature Packet, old CTB, 590 bytes               <-- Self-signature that binds
    Version: 4                                         the user ID to the main key.
    Type: PositiveCertification
    [...]
  
User Attribute Packet, new CTB, 10507 bytes        <-- The attached photo.
    JPEG: 10485 bytes
  
Signature Packet, old CTB, 613 bytes               <-- Self-signature that binds
    Version: 4                                         the photo to the main key.
    Type: PositiveCertification
    [...]
  
Public-Subkey Packet, old CTB, 525 bytes           <-- Another RSA keypair,
    Version: 4                                         used for encryption.
    Creation time: 2019-02-27 07:17:09 UTC
    Pk algo: RSA
    Pk size: 4096 bits
    Fingerprint: 9CE63B2147B377C9A91EC2B7FB1A4AE6E362917B
    KeyID: FB1A4AE6E362917B
  
Signature Packet, old CTB, 543 bytes               <-- Self-signature that binds
    Version: 4                                         the subkey to the main key.
    Type: SubkeyBinding
    [...]
```